# Shopping during Pesach

Tags: passover

Should one go to the store to shop during Chag haMatzot (Pesach), being that we have to stay away from chametz and leavening agents during the time?

Comment: Shopping for what? Electronics? Clothing? Food? Anything?

Comment: Grocery stores.

Answer (score 2):

Ex. 13:17 states:

> מצות יאכל את שבעת הימים **ולא יראה לך** חמץ **ולא יראה לך** שאר
> בכל-גבלך
>
> Masoth shall be eaten throughout the seven day period; no hames may be
> seen in your possession, nor may leaven be seen in your possession in
> all your borders.

One might erroneously conclude that seeing in and of itself is prohibited. However the word לך (your) teaches us that though we are prohibited from retaining possession of hames, we are not prohibited from seeing the hames of others.

This is as is stated in H. Hames u'Masah 3:1:

> לא יראה לך שלך אי אתה רואה אבל אתה רואה של אחרים
>
> "No [leaven] shall be seen for you." [We may infer]: You may not see
> your own [leaven]. However, you may see [leaven] belonging to others

See there for further details (e.g. the permissibility of seeing hames owned by a gentile that was left with a Jew over Passover, etc.).

Accordingly, there is no problem with shopping or venturing out into the gentile world where one may visually encounter hames. The important thing is that we do not take any into our possession.